# Drupal rest services in Json format

Tags: rest, drupal, android-service

I am working on drupal 7. I created a rest services in drupal views. I want to consume this service in my android app. When i try to view my service

http://mysite.com/ubercart/?q=rest/views/doctor

am getting response like this

> [{,"foaf:Document"],"title":{"predicates":["dc:title"]},"created":{"predicates":["dc:date","dc:created"],"datatype":"xsd:dateTime","callback":"date_iso8601"},"changed":{"predicates":["dc:modified"],"datatype":"xsd:dateTime","callback":"date_iso8601"},"body":{"predicates":[""vid":"12","uid":"1","title":"raja","log":"","status":"1","comment":"2","promote":"0","sticky":"0","nid":"12","type":"doctor","language":"und","created":"1351849158","changed":"1351849158","tnid":"0","translate":"0","revision_timestamp":"1351849158","revision_uid":"1","field_rating":{"und":[{"value":"4"}]},"field_place":{"und":[{"value":"Guntur","format":null,"safe_value":"Guntur"}]},"rdf_mapping":{"rdftype":["sioc:Item","foaf:Document"],"title":{"predicates":["dc:title"]},"created":{"predicates":["dc:date","dc:created"],"datatype":"xsd:dateTime","callback":"date_iso8601"},"changed":{"predicates":["dc:modified"],"datatype":"xsd:dateTime","callback":"date_iso8601"},"body":{"predicates":["content:encoded"]},"uid":{"predicates":["sioc:has_creator"],"type":"rel"},"name":{"predicates":["foaf:name"]},"comment_count":{"predicates":["sioc:num_replies"],"datatype":"xsd:integer"},"last_activity":{"predicates":["sioc:last_activity_date"],"datatype":"xsd:dateTime","callback":"date_iso8601"}},"cid":"0","last_comment_timestamp":"1351849158","last_comment_name":null,"last_comment_uid":"1","comment_count":"0","name":"admin","picture":"0","data":"b:0;","uc_order_product_id":false,"ucnc_product_nid":false},{"vid":"11","uid":"1","title":"ravi","log":"","status":"1","comment":"2","promote":"0","sticky":"0","nid":"11","type":"doctor","language":"und","created":"1351849131","changed":"1351849131","tnid":"0","translate":"0","revision_timestamp":"1351849131","revision_uid":"1","field_rating":{"und":[{"value":"5"}]},"field_place":{"und":[{"value":"Hyderabad","format":null,"safe_value":"Hyderabad"}]},"rdf_mapping":{"rdftype":["sioc:Item","foaf:Document"],"title":{"predicates":["dc:title"]},"created":{"predicates":["dc:date","dc:created"],"datatype":"xsd:dateTime","callback":"date_iso8601"},"changed":{"predicates":["dc:modified"],"datatype":"xsd:dateTime","callback":"date_iso8601"},"body":{"predicates":["content:encoded"]},"uid":{"predicates":["sioc:has_creator"],"type":"rel"},"name":{"predicates":["foaf:name"]},"comment_count":{"predicates":["sioc:num_replies"],"datatype":"xsd:integer"},"last_activity":{"predicates":["sioc:last_activity_date"],"datatype":"xsd:dateTime","callback":"date_iso8601"}},"cid":"0","last_comment_timestamp":"1351849131","last_comment_name":null,"last_comment_uid":"1","comment_count":"0","name":"admin","picture":"0","data":"b:0;","uc_order_product_id":false,"ucnc_product_nid":false},{"vid":"10","uid":"1","title":"sree","log":"","status":"1","comment":"2","promote":"0","sticky":"0","nid":"10","type":"doctor","language":"und","created":"1351849109","changed":"1351849109","tnid":"0","translate":"0","revision_timestamp":"1351849109","revision_uid":"1","field_rating":{"und":[{"value":"4"}]},"field_place":{"und":[{"value":"Hyderabad","format":null,"safe_value":"Hyderabad"}]},"rdf_mapping":{"rdftype":["sioc:Item"content:encoded"]},"uid":{"predicates":["sioc:has_creator"],"type":"rel"},"name":{"predicates":["foaf:name"]},"comment_count":{"predicates":["sioc:num_replies"],"datatype":"xsd:integer"},"last_activity":{"predicates":["sioc:last_activity_date"],"datatype":"xsd:dateTime","callback":"date_iso8601"}},"cid":"0","last_comment_timestamp":"1351849109","last_comment_name":null,"last_comment_uid":"1","comment_count":"0","name":"admin","picture":"0","data":"b:0;","uc_order_product_id":false,"ucnc_product_nid":false}]

Actually i need response like this

> {"nodes":{"0":{"node":{"title":"raja","field_place":"Guntur","rating":"4"}},"1":{"node":{"title":"ravi","field_place":"Hyderabad","rating":"5"}},"2":{"node":{"title":"sree","field_place":"Hyderabad","rating":"4"}}}}

Can any one help me out?

Comment: Please include the code you tried.

Comment: I installed services 3x module in drupal 7 and created  a service view for my existing view. When i call my service view with above url. am getting that response. I didnt use any code.

Answer (score 0):

I find the sollution above.. Some sites took me in wrong direction. The url is

http://mysite.com/ubercart/?q=rest/doctor

I got the format which i need. Also i found servces 3x version has some troubles with json format weservices. It worked good for me in xml formatter.